# SignalR : self-hosted scaleout options

Tags: signalr, signalr-backplane

Currently we are using SignalR self-hosted in a Windows service (also using SSL).  This is used to push different types of updates to the clients (ASP MVC application).  This is all working pretty good.

We are now however looking at the options to provide a highly available solution.  As the windows signalr service is a single point of failure for the moment, it's considered as a weak spot.

I've been looking at the scaleout options that are provided by signalr, but I can't find a lot of information about this (in combination with self-hosting).  For the moment I have following questions:
- Is it possible to use these scaleout options in a self hosted SignalR service?
- If not, are there other options we could look at?

Comment: I am currently experiencing issues with this. Seems that the tokens used to generate `ConnectionId` cannot be easily shared when scaling out with self hosted Signalr. No machine key in the web.config as you would on vanilla IIS hosted ASP.NET.

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution to this problem?

Comment: @NicoCV I only very recently received your message to me on the main asp.net site.  Please leave a follow up comment here if it is still relevant to you and I will do my best to assist.

Comment: Hi guys. Did you solve it? or not yet